# how to handle the type from optional in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

how can I set the type for my `localparaB` in my case? that I need to iterate through the optional parameter

```
function func(paraB?:string[]): string[]
{
  const localparaB = paraB.map((n) => `${n}-vvv`)
  return localparaB 
}
console.log(func(['a', 'b']))
```

Comment: What *are* you planning to do when paraB is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`optional chaining operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [`nullish coalescing operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), like:

```
function func(paraB?:string[]): string[] {
  const localparaB = paraB?.map((n) => `${n}-vvv`) ?? []

  return localparaB
}

console.log(func(['a', 'b']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Typescrip gaurds concept meaning adding a if clasue as a gaurd:

```
function func(paraB?:string[]): string[]
{
    if (paraB) {
        const localparaB = paraB.map((n) => `${n}-vvv`)
        return localparaB
    }
}
console.log(func(['a', 'b']))
```